# Can't call another method in my controller using 'render'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to create a multi button form. The if I press "create checked" it does create copyies is it is should do. I have created the routes.

My controller:

```
  def create_multiple
    @webhost = Webhost.find(params[:webhost_ids])
    if params[:delete_button]
     render 'admin/webhosts/delete_multiple'
    else
    @webhost.each do |webhost|
    Webhost.create(webhost.attributes)
    end
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to(:admin_webhosts, :notice => 'Konkurrancerne er nu slettet') }
      format.xml  { head :ok }
    end
end

def delete_multiple
    @webhost = Webhost.find(params[:webhost_ids])
    @webhost.each do |webhost|
    webhost.destroy
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to(:admin_webhosts, :notice => 'Konkurrancerne er nu slettet') }
      format.xml  { head :ok }
    end
end
```

In my view I have:

```
<%= submit_tag "Create Checked" %>  
<%= submit_tag "Delete Checked", :name => 'delete_button' %>
```

When I press the delete checked button I get this error:
Template is missing

```
Missing template admin/webhosts/delete_multiple with {:handlers=>[:erb, :rjs, :builder, :rhtml, :rxml], :formats=>[:html], :locale=>[:en, :en]} in view paths "C:/Rails/webhostapp/app/views", "C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/devise-1.1.5/app/views", "C:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/kaminari-0.10.4/app/views", "C:/Rails/webhostapp", "C:/"
```

And the URL is: `http://localhost:3000/admin/webhosts/create_multiple`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I see correctly, you want to call `delete_multiple` when the button is clicked.

If `delete_multiple` is a method of your controller, **you don't call it via `render`**. `render` will try to look for a view called `admin/webhosts/delete_multiple.html.erb` or similar and show that view. See [Layouts and Rendering in Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html) for more on that.

What you probably want to do is just call this method as usual:

```
def create_multiple
    @webhost = Webhost.find(params[:webhost_ids])
    if params[:delete_button]
     delete_multiple(params) and return
    else
    # ...
end
```

Note that you probably need to pass the parameters to your `delete_multiple` method. You will have to adapt it to take the parameters as an argument of course:

```
def delete_multiple(params)
    @webhost = Webhost.find(params[:webhost_ids])
    @webhost.each do |webhost|
    webhost.destroy
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to(:admin_webhosts, :notice => 'Konkurrancerne er nu slettet') }
      format.xml  { head :ok }
    end
end
```

Comment: I get a :DoubleRenderError in Admin::WebhostsController#create_multiple

Comment: I moved the end and it did fix the problem

Comment: Try again, I fixed my code now. `and return` assures that all subsequent calls to `render` from `create_multiple` are skipped. You shouldn't need to move anything.